# Not able to get value of in callback function in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need a passed value. This is my code:

```
function parseArticle(i, bookmark_id, bookmark_url, callback) {
        console.log("Value of i is " + i);
        console.log("Value of Bookmark_id is coming " + bookmark_id);
        diffbot.article({uri: bookmark_url}, function(err, response) {
            console.log("Value of Bookmark_id "+bookmark_id);
```

My problem is bookmark_id under diffbot.article is undefined. But under parseArticle is coming fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Where are the arguments? :/

Comment: parseArticle(i,bookmark_id,bookmark_url,callbackForParseArticle); I  amcalling this function

Comment: those are parameters, where are the actual arguments or the values you passed to a function?

Comment: I am getting Bookmark_id under parseArticle ..

Comment: Just not getting Value under diffbot.article

Comment: Shouldn't you be using/logging `response` and not `bookmark_id`? That's what the callback is being passed...

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how node.js and the whole idea of asynchronous requests and callbacks work.

Quite simply you are trying to access the argument `bookmark_id` inside the callback for `diffbot.article`. However, the function `parseArticle` is already executed and doesn't wait for the callback function for `diffbot.article` to get finished as it **not** synchronous by design. Therefore all the arguments passed to `parseArticle` are out of scope in the callbacks for functions used inside it and thus you get a lexical scope issue.

I suggest reading about Asynchronous requests and the idea of closures in this pretty well written [blog post](http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/08/26/asynchronous-code-design-with-node-js/). Hope it gets you started in the right direction.